# How to sort a list of string ignoring whitespace in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting

```
Str1=["Josephine","Joseph smith"]
```

Josephine should come first but due to space Joseph smith comes first.

Comment: That's not a duplicate: it shows how to remove whitespace, but not how to use it as a basis for a sort key.

Answer (score 9):

What you're describing is:

```
>>> Str1 = ['Josephine', 'Joseph smith']
>>> sorted(Str1)
['Joseph smith', 'Josephine']
```

You can provide a `key` to [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) or [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) to make your string comparisons ignore whitespace:

```
>>> sorted(Str1, key=lambda x: ''.join(x.split()))
['Josephine', 'Joseph smith']
```

Comment: A rather convoluted way to remove whitespace, also will replace newline characters which may not be desired, why not just use `replace()`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) includes newlines (and tabs), and is what the question explicitly asks to be ignored in the title.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Okay I agree

Answer (score 3):

You pass in a sort key that replaces all space character with an empty string:

```
Str1.sort(key=lambda k: k.replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can do it this way:

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x:x.replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: Just `sorted(my_string, key=lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''))` is fine

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus you are right! Edited my answer, thank you!